# Autoload error: An abstract factory could not create an instance in magento2

Tags: magento2, cli

After I created a new module in Magento 2, I'm getting this error. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Running:

```
$ bin/magento module:status
```

Error:

> `Autoload error: An abstract factory could not create an instance of magentosetupconsolecommandconfigsetcommand(alias: Magento\Setup\Console\Command\ConfigSetCommand).root`

Comment: Please provide more details eg. steps to reproduce, show your module code.

Comment: If you provide the full stack trace it will make it easier to help you.

Comment: It seems you get this error when there's a mistake in your module.xml file. If you go to the magento backend and try to clear the cache, you'll probably get a better error message. Make sure developer mode is activated though.

Comment: It can be intl PHP extension disabled issue. I have same after enabling this extension this issue resolved